# How do i fix a "FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: vb.net

I am doing some coding for my school project and I'm trying to create a program that uses filters and displays a set of items based on those queries. However, when writing the SQL statement, i get a FormatException.

Here is my line of code:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM partList WHERE [price] = '" & filterMinPrice And filterMaxPrice & "'AND [size] = '" & filterMicroATX And filterATX & "'AND [usability] = '" & filterHomeUse And filterSemiIntensive And filterHighIntensive)
```

and this is the error i receive:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "SELECT * FROM
> partList WHERE [pr" to type 'Long' is not valid.' FormatException:
> Input string was not in a correct format.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Always use parameters. Do not concatenate strings to build an sql query.

Comment: As Mary wrote, always use SQL parameters to add the parameter values to the query. I expect that you will notice why the error message happened when you have done that.

Comment: Besides the obvious, using parameterized queries: What do you expect an expression like `"SELECT * FROM partList WHERE [price] = '" & filterMinPrice And filterMaxPrice & "'...` to do? What are `filterMinPrice` and `filterMaxPrice`

Comment: Try explaining what you're actually trying to achieve, rather then expecting us to work it out from code that doesn't do it. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Are filterMinPrice and filterMaxPrice flags the you are adding? And is not part of your string. What types are price, size and usability in the database. The first 2 should be numeric types but you are passing strings. When you say And in a query string you are adding another condition but a single variable is not a condition.

Answer (score 0):

I have demonstrated how to use parameters. Your main problem was in your logic in the query string. Each section of the `Where` clause  separated by an `And` or `Or` must evaluate to True or False. Think about it. The price couldn't equal both the Max and Min.
You will have to check the database to see the correct datatypes of the fields because I had to guess. The `Using...End Using` block ensures that the connection is closed and disposed and the command is disposed.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Private Function GetPartData(filterMinPrice As Decimal, filterMaxPrice As Decimal, filterMicroATX As Integer, filterATX As Integer, filterHomeUse As String, filterSemiIntensive As String, filterHighIntensive As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM partList 
                WHERE [price] > @MinPrice 
                And [price] < @MaxPrice 
                AND [size] > @MicroATX 
                And [size] < @ATX 
                AND [usability] = @HomeUse 
                Or [usability] = @SemiIntensive 
                Or [usability] = @HighIntensive;"
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@MinPrice", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = filterMinPrice
            .Add("@MaxPrice", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = filterMaxPrice
            .Add("@MicroATX", OleDbType.Integer).Value = filterMicroATX
            .Add("@ATX", OleDbType.Integer).Value = filterATX
            .Add("@HomeUse", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = filterHomeUse
            .Add("@SemiIntensive", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = filterSemiIntensive
            .Add("@HighIntensive", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = filterHighIntensive
        End With
        con.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```